# Getting payment info on <sales_order_place_after> help?

Tags: magento-1.7

Here us the whole thing that i am not able to solve it. i am trying to pass all order info, customer info and payment info through an event oberver  and inserting to another db. Right now everything is working fine and i successfully insert order info,customer info. What i can not get is the payment info such as credit card info, authorization code info.

Here is my code:

On the config.xml file i have this event observer:

```
<sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <insertorder_orderexport>
                    <class>insertorder_orderexport/observer</class>
                    <method>exportOrder</method>
                </insertorder_orderexport>
            </observers>
</sales_order_place_after>
```

On my function i have this observer.php i have this code:

```
class InsertOrder_OrderExport_Model_Observer {


public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    Mage::getModel('insertorder_orderexport/export')->exportOrder($order);

return true;

}
```

}

on my export.php i have this code:

```
class InsertOrder_OrderExport_Model_Export
{

public function exportOrder($order)
{

    include('classes.php');

 $getCcInfo = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->setPageSize(1)->setOrder('created_at')->getFirstItem();
    $order_data = $getCcInfo->getPayment()->getData('additional_information');

    if(!empty($order_data)){

    foreach($order_data as $value){

        $aPayment = new OrderPayment;
        $aPayment->CreditCardNumber    = $value['cc_last4'];
        $aPayment->AuthorisationNumber = $value['approval_code'];
    }

    }
```

The code continue with other classes and insertions like order and customer info but eveything is tested and works fine beside this block of code which ends up empty.

The strange thing is that when i test this code on magento root folder i get the results i want lets say when i print_r($order_data); i get this result:

```
Array
(

[1dccc017a3fa2a84bad51ece5cbffd20] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1dccc017a3fa2a84bad51ece5cbffd20
        [requested_amount] => 
        [balance_on_card] => 
        [last_trans_id] => 2201005063
        [processed_amount] => 6.94
        [cc_type] => VI
        [cc_owner] => 
        [cc_last4] => 1111
        [cc_exp_month] => 4
        [cc_exp_year] => 2018
        [cc_ss_issue] => 
        [cc_ss_start_month] => 
        [cc_ss_start_year] => 
        [approval_code] => 8Z0LNX
    )
)
```

So it means that $order_data is full with values but i don't understand why it ends up empty after.

Also i have tried other events like:

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

checkout_submit_all_after
```

Still no results. And i don't have any error in my log file.

Please professional users help me, Thank you

Comment: try to replace `include('classes.php');` with `require_once('classes.php)` you may have an include issue. FYI: for me it's bad practice to put an include in such a place.

Comment: I have replaced but the problem is not there because i can successfully insert strings for testing. However thank you :)

Comment: `$order` is never used in `function exportOrder`. Any reasons?

Comment: is used, there are other 100 line of codes but i don't wanted to post it all here, i posted only where my issue is present. The other values and codes are tested and they work fine Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to remove the foreach loop.

```
foreach($order_data as $value){
    // $value is now $order_data['id'] or some such
    // and when you call $value['cc_last4']
    // you're mistakenly looking in $order_data['id']['cc_last4']
}
```

Just use this instead:

```
if(!empty($order_data)){
    $aPayment = new OrderPayment;
    $aPayment->CreditCardNumber    = $value['cc_last4'];
    $aPayment->AuthorisationNumber = $value['approval_code'];
}
```

Comment: Nope Sir even that did not worked. If i remove foreach i get an error of Undefined index: cc_last4 and approval_code. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

For all other people that will have this issue this is how is solved:

I had to change the event from:

```
<sales_order_place_after>
```

to

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

and changed my observer.php like this:

```
public function exportOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData('additional_information');
    Mage::getModel('insertorder_orderexport/export')->exportOrder($order,$payment);
    Mage::log($payment);

return true;

}
```

and my function export.php to:

```
if(!empty($payment)){

        $data = $payment['authorize_cards'];

        foreach($data as $value){

            $aPayment->CreditCardNumber     = $value['cc_last4'];
            $aPayment->AuthorisationNumber  = $value['last_trans_id'];
        }

    }
```

This worked and sure it will work for you too guys. Thank you for your answers.